# Find If Objects in Collection have same field values

Tags: java, collections, equals, jtree

I'm attempting to create an editor to edit multiple devices that are selected in a JTree.

If items in the Collection all have the same value for a certain field, I will display that value in the editor form. If they have different Values, i will display "Multiple Values"

I have attempted to utilize something like this, but it is limited to comparing two items. I want to do it for all items in a collection.

```
 private static List<String> difference(Student s1, Student s2) {
 List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
 for (Field field : s1.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    // You might want to set modifier to public first (if it is not public yet)
    field.setAccessible(true);
    Object value1 = field.get(s1);
    Object value2 = field.get(s2); 
    if (value != null && value != null) {
        System.out.println(field.getName() + "=" + value1);
        System.out.println(field.getName() + "=" + value2);
        if (!Objects.equals(value1, value2) {
            values.add(value2);
        }
    }
}
return values;
```

}

Can someone provide an example of how you determine the fields that have the same values for Objects in a Collection?

My Hash and Equals code is below. I'm assuming this can be accomplished utilizing built in methods of Collection, but I'd appreciate an example.

```
    @Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 5;
    hash = 47 * hash + (this.isSelected ? 1 : 0);
    hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.user);
    hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.password);
    hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.address);
    hash = 47 * hash + (int) (this.addressAsLong ^ (this.addressAsLong >>> 32));
    hash = 47 * hash + this.port;
    hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.vendor);
    hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.model);
    hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.OS);
    hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.description);
    hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.version);
    hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.hostName);
    hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.domain);
    hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.deviceType);
    hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.Location);
    hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.SerialNumber);
    // hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.parent);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final DefaultDevice other = (DefaultDevice) obj;
    if (this.isSelected != other.isSelected) {
        System.out.println("isSelected");
        return false;
    }
    if (this.addressAsLong != other.addressAsLong) {
        // System.out.println("long");
        return false;
    }
    if (this.port != other.port) {
        //System.out.println("port");
        return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.user, other.user)) {
        // System.out.println("user");
        return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.password, other.password)) {
        //System.out.println("pass");
        return false;
    }

    if (!Objects.equals(this.vendor, other.vendor)) {
        //System.out.println("ven");
        return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.model, other.model)) {
        //System.out.println("mod");
        return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.OS, other.OS)) {
        // System.out.println("os");
        return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.description, other.description)) {
        //System.out.println("des");
        return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.version, other.version)) {
        //System.out.println("ver");
        return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.hostName, other.hostName)) {
        // System.out.println("hostNa");
        return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.domain, other.domain)) {
        // System.out.println("dom");
        return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.deviceType, other.deviceType)) {
        // System.out.println("dt");
        return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.Location, other.Location)) {
        //System.out.println("loc");
        return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.SerialNumber, other.SerialNumber)) {
        // System.out.println("sn");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Loop through the collection while checking for the field value - break when found more than one

Comment: Please show your [mcve] code including telling us what you've tried and how it's not working.

Comment: Thank you for posting code, but I'm afraid that I don't see your own attempt to solve this within your posted code. Am I missing it? Please clarify and improve if possible.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels IMO the OP put quite an effort even though he was not successful. For the rest see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comprehensive solution taking into account accessibility, use of getters/setters instead of field access etc. will require quite a bit of effort, but within the scope of what you describe the algorithm may look like this:

- in your method return an object of the type your iterate over as result and take one with default values for the mismatch case (replace those with `Map<String, Object>` if you like)
- get the first item out of non-empty collection and determine its class
- iterate through all the declared fields, for each taking the value from the first item and then iterating via items until the first mismatch
- if mismatched, assign the value from the defaults and break the iteration
- set the found value to the result field and move to the next field

In code it looks like this:

```
class ObjectMatcher {

    // NPE on null items
    // assumes public default constructor for T is available
    public <T> T match(Collection<T> items, T defaults) {
        if (items.isEmpty()) {
            return defaults;
        }
        try {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>) items.iterator().next().getClass();
            Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();

            T res = clazz.newInstance();

            for (Field field : fields) {
                boolean firstItem = true;
                Object match = null;
                for (T item : items) {
                    Object value = field.get(item);
                    if (firstItem) {
                        match = value;
                    }
                    else if (!Objects.equals(value, match)) {
                        match = field.get(defaults);
                        break;
                    } // otherwise keep the match as is
                    firstItem = false;
                }
                field.set(res, match);
            }
            return res;
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is a simple test for the case of field mismatch, match and null/non-null mismatch:

```
@Test
public void match_onMistmatchMatchAndNull_ok() {
    Student s1 = new Student("Andrew", "Physics", null);
    Student s2 = new Student("Joe", "Physics", 3.45);
    Student s3 = new Student("Nicki", "Physics", 2.39);

    Student defaults = new Student("Multiple Names", "Multiple Courses", 1.0);

    ObjectMatcher matcher = new ObjectMatcher();
    Student res = matcher.match(Arrays.asList(s1, s2, s3), defaults);

    assertEquals("Multiple Names", res.name);
    assertEquals("Physics", res.course);
    assertEquals(1.0, res.grade.doubleValue(), 0.001);
}
```

You will find the complete code for the test class on the [dedicated GitHub repo](https://github.com/osklyar/stack-overflow/blob/master/src/test/java/TestObjectMatcher.java).

Comment: That is a very good answer. ObjectMatcher seems to be the piece I was missing.

Comment: Thanks. I am glad it helped. It is unfortunate people downvoted your question, to me it looks a very valid one with sufficient effort spent on trying to solve it on your own. Good luck

Comment: Could you have a look at this question as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50682332/treecelleditor-for-multi-node-editing